# how to rewrite head.phtml in magento

Tags: php, magento, templates

I want to change the page title in magento. 
In my `app/design/frontend/default/customPackage/template/page/html/head.phtml`, there are lines control all page title(what I want just to modify the catalog page's title)

```
<title>
<?php 
     if ($current_product = Mage::registry('current_product')) { 
        echo substr($current_product->getName() . " - " . Mage::helper('core')->currency($current_product->getFinalPrice(), true, false),0,69);
    } else {

        echo substr(str_replace("- Products","",$this->getTitle()),0,100);
    }
     ?></title>
```

but I don't want to modify directly from head.phtml in `app/design/frontend/default/customPackage/template/page/html`, instead, I want to replace this `head.phtml` with another `head.phtml` in my own module tempate files.Let's say , make it `app/design/frontend/default/customPackage/template/catalog/html/head.phtml` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, basically we need to find where is `page/html/head.phtml` file is defined. Answer is in layout files, more specifically in `page.xml`. Location is :`app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/page.xml`. Inside that file, under the handle `<default>`, you can see

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            -------
        </block>
         ---------
    </block>
</default>
```

Where

- `<default>` is known as layout handler. Blocks that comes under this
  handler will show in every page in magento.
- block `page/html` is your root block. It is the parent block of all other blocks. There should be only one root block per page. You can reference this block using its name `root` in your custom layout files, in order to alter anything inside this block.
- block `page/html_head` is the block which is referenced in your question. This block is use to hold the `<head />` section of your page (in terms of html tree). You can see that magento loads some of its core javascripts and css inside this block.

But `page/html_head` is not set with any template as you already see. Then how `page/html/head.phtml` came to the seen ??? It should set somewhere in magento. So let us go the backend side of this block, where all of its block methods are defined. The file location is `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php`. Yes we found out it.

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
/**
 * Initialize template
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('page/html/head.phtml');
}
 ------
}
```

So Magento set template for `page/html_head` block here, through `_construct()` method. Change it to your template location

```
 protected function _construct()
 {
    $this->setTemplate('app/design/frontend/default/customPackage/template/catalog/html/head.phtml');
 }
```

It will now set location of `page/html_head` block to your custom template file.

If you want to the block file is also untouched, you can rewrite this block file using your own module. In your config.xml file, you should use this

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_head>Namespace_Modulename_Block_Html_Head</html_head>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

and you should define a block file in `app/code/local/Namespace/Moduleame/Block/Html/Head.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head 
{
     protected function _construct()
     {
        $this->setTemplate('app/design/frontend/default/customPackage/template/catalog/html/head.phtml');
     }
}
```

This way core files are untouched and still you can alter the template path.

Comment: Using the `<rewrite>` method at the bottom of your answer is the best solution. Thanks!