# How to use custom "Head.phtml" for a Magento CMS page?

Tags: magento, head, php

Im running a Magento 1.9 Online Shop and I want to use a customized search site.

I created a CMS Page "search.html" in the backend.

This site includes a Search Form via .phtml file with some PHP Code inside. If you search for your keyword, the URL becomes "domain.de/search.html?query=KEYWORD".

I need to set the KEYWORD, if given, as Meta Title and Description Tag of my search page with PHP.

Today I spend 6 hours looking for a solution. Unfortunately im a Magento Newbie.
I think the best way for me is to use my PHP Code in "head.phtml" file to change the Page Title and Description.

**Is there a way to replace the "head.phtml" file of my template only for this one special Magento CMS Page?** (so the rest of my template remains untouched)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look this answer. That's one is step by step what you have done for override **head.phtml**. Hope this help!

[how to rewrite head.phtml in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373670/how-to-rewrite-head-phtml-in-magento)

Comment: Ty. I´ve found this before. But this describes how to set a custom head.phtml for all pages. I only need to load a seperate head.phtml for a CMS site. Unfortunately I´m Magento beginner and have no clue how to use a Module or XMS file to tell magento it should change the head file for only one cms site